# Try to importxml wildcard character function

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula, wildcard

I am using importxml function to extract some info

```
=IMPORTXML("url","//span[@class='circle-with-text grade-D']")
```

I need to replace D with any other letter,trying to  use "*" or '*' or '?' etc with no results.
"AN?" idea?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

`'=IMPORTXML("url","//span[@class='circle-with-text grade-D']")'.replace(/D/,"A");` It's the only capital D.

Comment: =IMPORTXML("url","//span[@class='circle-with-text grade-"?"']")  or =IMPORTXML("url","//span[@class='circle-with-text grade-"/?*/"']") doesnt work whatever

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215).

As per the Help Docs:

> `SUBSTITUTE`
>
> Replaces existing text with new text in a string.
>
> `SUBSTITUTE(text_to_search, search_for, replace_with, [occurrence_number])`
>
> - `text_to_search` - The text within which to search and replace.
> - `search_for` - The string to search for within `text_to_search`.
>
>   - `search_for` will match parts of words as well as whole words; therefore a search for `"vent"` will also replace text within `"eventual"`.
> - `replace_with` - The string that will replace `search_for`.
> - `occurrence_number` - [ OPTIONAL ] - The instance of `search_for` within `text_to_search` to replace with `replace_with`. By default, all occurrences of `search_for` are replaced; however, if `occurrence_number` is specified, only the indicated instance of `search_for` is replaced.

So:

```
=IMPORTXML("url",SUBSTITUTE("//span[@class='circle-with-text grade-D']", "D", "A"))
```

replaces all `D`s in the formula with `A`s.

Comment: is nice, but I dont want to replace the result, but to replace the class parameter D inside the importxml

Comment: I understand - you can put the substitute inside the second parameter in this case. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @borcan22 did my updated answer solve the issue?